# Webclient not interpreting enter character correctly in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, webclient, character, enter

I've got a problem using WebClient.UploadStringAsync method. I've to do a POST request with some info to an external server, and in that request, I've to include the text cointained in a TextBox.

What I do is the following:

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.someweb.com");
string request = "{\"requests\":[\"sendMessage\",{\"body\":\"" + newMessageTextBox.Text + "\"}]}";

WebClient wb = new WebClient();
wb.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(nb_UploadStringCompleted);
wb.UploadStringAsync(url, "Post", request);
```

There is no problem, but if I include a message with a return, something like
"Hello

everybody"
the server gives back an error. If I sniff my traffic with Wireshark, I can see my POST request but it is as follows:

> "{"requests":["sendMessage",{"body":"Hello
>
> everybody"}]}"

While what I want to send is

> "{"requests":["sendMessage",{"body":"Hello\n\neverybody"}]}"

Any ideas??

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to perform appropriate JSON escaping. Personally I would use a JSON library for this - I've used [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com) within Windows Phone 7 and it's worked fine.

You'd build up your request as a JSON object - so without specifying the JSON text form itself at all - and then ask it to format itself into a string (just by calling `ToString`). For example:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "Hello\neverybody";

        JObject json = new JObject 
        {
            { "requests", new JArray 
                {
                    new JObject
                    {
                        { "sendMessage", new JObject 
                            {
                                { "body", text }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "sendMessage": {
        "body": "Hello\neverybody"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

(Obviously you don't need to use as much whitespace as that if you don't want to. You don't have to use object initializers either.)

EDIT: Okay, with changes as requested:

```
JObject json = new JObject 
{
    { "sid", sid },
    { "version", "0.6" },
    { "requests", new JArray 
        {
            new JArray
            {
                new JObject
                {
                    { "sendMessage", new JObject 
                        {
                            { "body", text },
                            { "recipient", recipient },
                            { "legacy", false },
                            { "thread_key", threadKey }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Result:

```
{
  "sid": "sid",
  "version": "0.6",
  "requests": [
    [
      {
        "sendMessage": {
          "body": "Hello\neverybody",
          "recipient": "foo@bar.com",
          "legacy": false,
          "thread_key": "T1"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for but I'm gettint an error when trying to do it myself, "Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject." Suppose it's my fault because I don't know how to do it, and what I posted wasn't exactly what I wanted to send, the exact thing is: "{\"session_id\":\"" + sid + "\",\"version\":\"0.6\",\"requests\":[[\"sendMessage\",{\"body\":\"" + newMessageTextBox.Text + "\",\"recipient\":\"" + counterPartUserId + "\",\"legacy\":false,\"thread_key\":\"" + threadKey + "\"}]]}";

Comment: @Jorge: I think you're missing a closing brace in the version in your comment - but see my edit for the appropriate code.

Comment: Ha! Indeed I were forgetting the braces you mentioned, but now I've got the opposite problem, I've too much \r's xD... Now what I'm trying to send is "{\r\n\"session_id\":\"abcd\",\r\n\"version\": \"0.6\",\r\n\"requests\":[\r\n{\r\n\"sendMessage\":[\r\n{\r\n\"body\": \"Te\\rst\",\r\n\"recipient\": 64834580,\r\n\"legacy\": false,\r\n\"thread_key\": \"13119501400059934348\"\r\n}\r\n]\r\n}\r\n]\r\n}"... Maybe I shouldn't use json.ToString()?? In that case, I can't use webclient.UploadStringAsync(url, "Post", json.ToString());

Comment: @Jorge: Sorry, it's very difficult to tell what's wrong when everythings just in a comment... What's the difference between what you're trying to send and what you're getting?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get the \r's just in the newMessageTextBox.Text part, not the rest, doing what you said return me \r's and \n's everywhere and also didn't scape the ", returned \"'s

Comment: @Jorge: Are you looking in the debugger, by any chance? Bear in mind that that will escape text for you. I suggest you look at the same string *in a file* or something similar. If you don't want the formatting, call `json.ToString(0)` instead.